# Check if android listview is scrolled down to the last item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in which there are several items. I want to check whether the list is scrolled down to the last item, in which case I want to run another method.How to do that?

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter?

Comment: yes, i use a custom adapter.

Comment: You need an endless list adpater. See here: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html

Comment: @vasudev that is useful.I will try implementing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at first set `isLoading = false;` in the constructore or `onCreate` method

```
  mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (mListView.getAdapter() == null)
                return ;

            if (mListView.getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
                return ;

            int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
            if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
                // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
                isLoading = true;
                loadData();

            }
        }
    });
```

and in function `loadData` you do something like:

```
 public void loadData() {

    // send your request
   // receive it by callback or asynctask
   yourDataList.addAll(newItems);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: @pratim do you have any problem by my solution?

Comment: i will check that and seems it will be useful for me.no vote up due to my low reputation.

Comment: i dont have any problem. i am not able to test as my ide ran into some problem.i will test implementing your solution soon.I will accept your answer as correct then..

Comment: @pratim if you want to download from internet or create an endless list it must change a little and must put a variable on it, if so tell me to fix that i mean if your newItems ready you do not need that varable but if it is not ready you must change it so it can request to download just one time.

Comment: i am planning to download from internet in a batch of 10 items.so in the first time load, i will get 10 items which will be displayed in the lv and will save batchNo field in my activity to 1.When lv is scrolled down to the 10th item i will run async task to retrieve 2nd batch with 10 items.Subsequently, on receiving items, i will update the lv and increment batchNo field.Are you talking about the batchNo field by variable?Or there are some other variable required?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `listView.getLastVisiblePosition()`.

Comment: i infact want to refresh the adapter with new data when last position is reached. how should i keep checking that while scrollling down?