# listview with gridview inside scrollview android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-gridview

i have a situation there is gridview when scrolling downward reach the last item listview visibillity to be visible and gridview to be gone when scrolling upward listView visibility to be gone and gridview to be visible

Comment: Can you please share your code that you have tried yet? It will help  others to understand your problem more accurately

Comment: there is no code it just a situation in my head want to do there is a grid view and listview together inside scrollview what i want is when i scroll with the gridview when it reach the last item of it listview appears and vice versa

Comment: you can use <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350137/check-if-android-listview-is-scrolled-down-to-the-last-item> to detect last item scrolled in list view.Once you detect this then you can easily toggle visibility of listView and GridView acc to your need.